# Query a pandas dataframe without header

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` with no header and I have to assign `string` type names to the columns to be able to use the pandas `query()` method.

```
df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C']
df.query('A > 0')
```

I'm wondering how can I query a DateFarame with no header?

Comment: can you give a exemple of query

Comment: df.query('A > 0') returns the rows in df in which the value of column A is greater than 0.

Comment: df [df['A'] > 0 ]

Comment: That's correct but doesn't use `query` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), when using `query`: *"You can refer to variables in the environment by prefixing them with an ‘@’ character"*

So, just as when your dataframe has a header ('A', 'B', ...), `df.query('A > 0')` is equivalent to `df.query("@df['A'] > 0")`

When you dataframe has no header, you can query like this: `df.query("@df[0] > 0")` ('0' for 'A', '1' for 'B', ...).